# What does var name = ()() do?

Tags: javascript, expression

I encountered the code like below.

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (!message) return reject(new Error('Requires message request to send'));
      message = (0, _getURLJWT)(message);
      .....
      .....
      var enc = (0, _encryptMessage)(plaintext, pubEncKey);

      }, function (error, res, body) {
       ....
       ....
      });
    });
```

I do not understand the two expressions in the code:

```
message = (0, _getURLJWT)(message);
var enc = (0, _encryptMessage)(plaintext, pubEncKey);
```

This looks like IIFE(Immediately invoked function expression), however, I do not understand how the brackets at the end of the line exactly work or what they are doing.

Could anyone help me understand this?

Comment: It is IIFE, and it looks like compiled code. Before modifying, check that it isn't generated/compiled code, because if it is, the source will be a lot easier to read. If that's the source, then the value in the brackets is the value to invoke the function with.

Comment: I was not initially aware that it was generated/compiled code.  I then checked and found that it was.  I found the source and it is indeed easier to read.  It was exactly what mrlew in another answer mentioned below `_getURLJWT(message)`.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_getURLJWT` and `_encryptMessage` are probably functions that are called with the arguments `message` and `plaintext, pubEncKey`, respectively.

When you write two values separeted by comma operator, Javascript evaluate all of its operands and returns the last one. So `0, 1` will evaluate `1`.

So, `(0, _getURLJWT)(message)` will evaluate to `_getURLJWT(message)`

For instance:

```
console.log((0,1)); //1

(0, (myArg) => console.log(myArg))('hello'); //hello
```

---

### Reason to use this technique

Calling this way ensures that the function is called with `this` set to the global object.

```
const myObj = {
    printMe: function() { console.log(this); },
}

myObj.printMe(); //{printMe: ƒ}

(0, myObj.printMe)(); // Window {parent: Window, opener: null...} <= loses reference, the this will not longer be bound to myObj, but will be bound to the global object.
```